# What is a minimal example of using Kafka with Python?

Tags: python, docker, apache-kafka

### What I tried

1. I cloned https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker and executed `sudo docker-compuse up`.
2. I started the `producer.py` listed below.
3. I started the `consumer.py` listed below.

This didn't work. I changed the `ports` of the `docker-compose.yml` to

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

After starting that, the `producer.py` finished execution and the docker-compose terminal showed

```
zookeeper_1  | 2018-09-05 14:21:44,001 [myid:] - INFO  [SessionTracker:ZooKeeperServer@358] - Expiring session 0x165aa1acb900000, timeout of 6000ms exceeded
zookeeper_1  | 2018-09-05 14:21:44,002 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2181)::PrepRequestProcessor@487] - Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x165aa1acb900000
kafka_1      | [2018-09-05 14:21:44,028] INFO Creating /controller (is it secure? false) (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient)
kafka_1      | [2018-09-05 14:21:44,033] INFO Result of znode creation at /controller is: OK (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient)
zookeeper_1  | 2018-09-05 14:21:44,141 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2181)::PrepRequestProcessor@649] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x165aa1c265e0000 type:delete cxid:0x32 zxid:0x6f txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/admin/reassign_partitions Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /admin/reassign_partitions
zookeeper_1  | 2018-09-05 14:21:44,152 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2181)::PrepRequestProcessor@649] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x165aa1c265e0000 type:delete cxid:0x34 zxid:0x70 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/admin/preferred_replica_election Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /admin/preferred_replica_election
zookeeper_1  | 2018-09-05 14:21:47,621 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2181)::PrepRequestProcessor@649] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x165aa1c265e0000 type:setData cxid:0x3c zxid:0x71 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/config/topics/mytopic Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /config/topics/mytopic
kafka_1      | [2018-09-05 14:21:47,628] INFO Topic creation Map(mytopic-0 -> ArrayBuffer(1003)) (kafka.zk.AdminZkClient)
kafka_1      | [2018-09-05 14:21:47,639] INFO [KafkaApi-1003] Auto creation of topic mytopic with 1 partitions and replication factor 1 is successful (kafka.server.KafkaApis)
```

The topic was created, that is good. But then, when I execute the consumers, they don't do anything. But docker-compose shows

```
kafka_1      | [2018-09-05 14:24:52,566] ERROR [KafkaApi-1003] Number of alive brokers '0' does not meet the required replication factor '1' for the offsets topic (configured via 'offsets.topic.replication.factor'). This error can be ignored if the cluster is starting up and not all brokers are up yet. (kafka.server.KafkaApis)
```

How can I have a minimal Kafka installation / setup to see Kafka working with Python?

### producer.py

```
from confluent_kafka import Producer

p = Producer({'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092'})
p.produce('mytopic', key='hello', value='world')
print("produce done")
p.flush(10)
```

### consumer.py

```
from confluent_kafka import Consumer, KafkaError


c = Consumer({
    'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092',
    'group.id': 'mygroup',
    'default.topic.config': {
        'auto.offset.reset': 'smallest'
    }
})

c.subscribe(['mytopic'])

while True:
    msg = c.poll(1.0)

    if msg is None:
        continue
    if msg.error():
        if msg.error().code() == KafkaError._PARTITION_EOF:
            continue
        else:
            print(msg.error())
            break

    print('Received message: {}'.format(msg.value().decode('utf-8')))

c.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this env section

```
  KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
  KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://localhost:9094
  KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://:9094
  KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
```

Add `9094:9094` to the ports and point Python at `localhost:9094` if you are not running your code inside a Python docker container

[The Confluent images have a similar setup](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/blob/5.0.0-post/examples/cp-all-in-one/docker-compose.yml#L25-L27), but port 29092 instead

Comment: More details here https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/